# How to change dev-master releases to stable composer

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, release

I am creating a sockets package in PHP for Laravel, but I can not just use the composer require because the package is in dev-master and of course I do not want to change my entire main application to accept packages in dev-master. Could someone help me make a release stable discoverable by packagist?

Comment: What has the usage of `composer require` got to do with your package being in dev-master (and what does that actually mean?)?

Comment: I have a package developed by me, but when I install it the following message appears "Could not find package marcuscampos / laravel-socket at any version for your minimum-stability (stable)." I want to solve this problem.

Comment: According to packagist there are multiple stable releases of that package, so it's probably the other project you're trying to install in that is acting up. That said, you can always `composer require marcuscampos/laravel-socket:dev-master`

Comment: @Loek is right, you already have stable releases. Please show the `composer.json` files for your package and for the parent project. The problem is probably in one of those.

Comment: I solved the problem, I lacked autoload in composer.json. Thank you!